# Is closed subset of irreducible irreducible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an irreducible topological space and $Y$ be closed subset of $X.$ Is $Y$ irreducible? I can prove that open subset of irreducible is irreducible but I'm unable to prove this for a closed subset. If the statement is not true can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: The space $\{1,2,3\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{3\}, \{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ is irreducible. The subset $\{1,2\}$ is closed, but it is the union of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, both closed.

Comment: Try a singleton.

Comment: thanks @arugula

Comment: Since you put those algebraic geometry tags ... You can just look at $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x])$, which is irreducible, but its closed subset $V(x(x-1))$ is the union of $V(x)$ and $V(x-1)$.

Comment: @arugula You have two good counterexamples here. Why did you post them as comments? Comments aren't for answering, answers are for answering.

Comment: @Arthur Things are not the way they are called, they are the way they behave.

Comment: @arugula And _you_ have the power to change that for the better.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the affine line ($Spec \mathbb{C}[x]$), and $V(x(x-1))$ the closed subset $\{0,1\}$. Then the former is irreducible, while the latter isn't, since it can be written as $\{0\}\cup \{1\}.$